# Laravel combine form submit and API request

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have a Laravel API that goes thru middleware and works just fine when called externally.

```
public function apiMethod(Request $request)
{
$requestData = $request->all();
dd($requestData);
}
```

In addition, I have a form that is processed by a method in a separate controller. In this method, I do a request to the API:

```
public function formHandler(Request $request)
{
    $request = \Request::create('/path/to/the/api/', 'POST', ['A' => 1]);
    $response = \Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
}
```

In this case, $requestData contains the form parameters instead of the array that I pass with my API request (['A' => 1]).

So I wonder what's the right approach to solve that issue in Laravel?

Comment: try like this ['A' => [1,2,3]]

Comment: you can use an helper and you call it from API and from controller

Comment: This problem is known on Laravel. You should instanciate a new `Request $request` to call your API, for now, `$request->all()` contains only the input of the current request, not the one you have created. Here is a solution : https://blog.antoine-augusti.fr/2014/04/laravel-calling-your-api/

Comment: This is how Laravel works: there is 1 request object per request lifecycle. This code seems weird in my opinion. Why would you want to send a request to code that lives in the same codebase? Why not call a function? That's orders of magniture quicker and more reliable.

Comment: instead of creating api request from controller for common functionality you can create service or helper and use it in api and controller

Comment: @VincentDecaux - your solution works but in my case there was additional data set in the request via the middleware. Thank you.

Comment: @Loek - Yes I've created a workaround to access the API directly.
Thank you.